# EndOfStreamException on primary server failover

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

When performing a failover on our cluster, the following `EndOfStreamException` is thrown every time (but only once) before the application successfully utilises the newly elected primary.

I am using 2.5.0 of the .NET Driver and also providing the replica set name in the connection string:

```
var url = MongoUrl.Create("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds012345-a0.mlab.com:56789,ds012345-a1.mlab.com:56790/<dbname>?replicaSet=rs-ds012345");

var client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings()
{
    Servers = url.Servers,
    Credentials = credentials
});
```

### Exception:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
>   receiving a message from the server. --->
>   System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the
>   stream.    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__52.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__54.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.<ExecuteProtocolAsync>d__26`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CommandOperationBase`1.<ExecuteProtocolAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.ReadCommandOperation`1.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__111.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.d__111.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.d__1`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.d__60`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same error, but it was coming alternatively. Once request success and second fail with the above error.

To solve this issue, I used `using` like below

```
using (var cursor = await _mongoDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(CollectionName)
                    .FindAsync(queryJson.ToString(), options))
                {
//operation
}
```

Please check if this resolves your issues too.
Thanks